# Correct way to fire and forget SignalR hub proxy tasks (C# Client)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

I am trying to fire and forget an event from my solution's business tier that basically notifies clients to increment a counter.

This is my current solution;

Lanching the task:

```
Task.Run(() => {
     try
     {
         NotifyUser(userID);
     } catch (Exception e) { //log here }
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The method itself:

```
private void NotifyUser(userID)
{
     var url = GetHubURL();
     using (var hubConnection = new HubConnection(url))
     {
          var notificationHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationHub");

          hubConnection.Start().Wait();
          notificationHub.Invoke("IncrementUserNonRead", userID);
     }
}
```

This is currently working in a real user case, but during functional testing it seemed like the connections were killed by the thread aborting, throwing warnings / errors and causing the operation to not be completed correctly half of the times. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Edit: Error stack trace:

```
vstest.executionengine.x86.exe Error: 0 : Error while closing the websocket: System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.WebSocketConnection.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.DelegatedStream.WriteAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<>n__FabricatedMethod14(Byte[] , Int32 , Int32 , CancellationToken )
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketConnectionStream.<WriteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<SendFrameAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.ThrowIfConvertibleException(String methodName, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean aborted)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<CloseOutputAsyncCore>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAwaiterHelper.PreserveCultureAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler.<>c.<<CloseAsync>b__13_0>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could share some of the errors you're getting

Comment: Sorry, added a stack trace to my OP

Comment: You are closing the connection (by disposing) before you completed sending. This code has more issues though - you should not start a connection just to send just one message. Starting a SignalR connection is costly (3 http request). You start a connection on a different thread only to block the thread by using .Wait() - even though all methods you call are async - just create an aync method an run it without awaiting. Observe exceptions on the returned Task though.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Do you think we should start the connexion to the hub in the Global.asax file and persist it?